# RxStomp service architecture in Angular

Tags: angular, stompjs

Following [this](https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/ng2-stompjs/ng2-stomp-with-angular7.html) guide for using stompjs in angular, I’m trying to figure the architecture for using it as a web socket to subscribe to live notifications thru a web socket I have.

In my root component I have 2 pages/components, which will be making use of the same topic to subscribe to. Is initiating the watch topic in root (app.component.ts) the correct or should I initiate the watch topic in the 2 respective components, and unsubscribe on destroy?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question. Let us discuss the behaviour closely.

The [watch](https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/ng2-stompjs/ng2-stomp-with-angular7.html#receiving-messages) is quite interesting. It returns an Observable Subject. On this `subject`, multiple subscribes (RxJS subscribes to be precise) can be invoked. There will still be a single underlying subscription. When the last subscription (RxJS) is unsubscribed, the underlying STOMP subscription will be unsubscribed.

So in the parent component, you should create the watch:

```js
watchTopic$ = this.rxStompService.watch('/topic/demo');
```

Pass `watchTopic$` to children (maybe as an input parameter or through a service).

Within each component:

```js
topicSubscription = watchTopic$.subscribe((message: Message) => {
      // use it
    });


// Typically onDestroy
topicSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Once this structure is set up, the underlying STOMP subscription will be initiated with the first active subscriber and will be terminated when the last subscriber goes away.

For reference, I am the person who wrote the guide referred to in the question.